# Jetbrains Exposed generating duplicate foreign keys

Tags: mysql, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I have this table schema:

```
object ValuesTable : IntIdTable("values") {
    val parameter =
        reference("parameters", ParametersTable, onDelete = ReferenceOption.CASCADE, onUpdate = ReferenceOption.CASCADE)
    val service =
        reference("services", ServicesTable, onDelete = ReferenceOption.CASCADE, onUpdate = ReferenceOption.CASCADE)
    val values = text("actual_values")
}
```

When exposed tries to create my table i'm getting `java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'fk_values_parameters_id'. I've tried manually adding a different **fkName**, also tried to use a different table name starting with uppercase.

MySQL version is : **Ver 8.0.19 for macos10.15 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused `SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns()`. Using simply `SchemaUtils.create()` works as expected